# ffmpeg: RTP missed many packets

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, rtsp, rtsp-client

I have an mp4 file named `test.mp4`, and I'm using VLC player as an RTSP server to convert the file `test.mp4` to the RTSP stream and send it to the client.

Here is how I configure my VLC to become a RTSP server: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfCKSIrIGlY

Then I login remotely my Linux machine, which is the client to receive the RTSP stream. To do so, I execute the below command on my Linux machine:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.120.157:5544/stream -c copy -f segment -segment_time 100 out_%d.mp4
```

After executing the command, I got two mp4 files. It seems that everything works as expected, except that I got many warnings:

```
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] max delay reached. need to consume packet=N/A speed=1.02x
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] RTP: missed 40 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] max delay reached. need to consume packet=N/A speed=1.02x
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] RTP: missed 6 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] RTP: missed 3 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] max delay reached. need to consume packet=N/A speed=1.02x
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] RTP: missed 45 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] RTP: missed 5 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] max delay reached. need to consume packet=N/A speed=1.02x
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] RTP: missed 22 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5a48580] max delay reached. need to consume packet
...
...
```

Is this normal? How can I solve these warnings?

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: @tmm1 Nop. It seems that RTSP always loses some packets. I guess maybe it's because of TCP mechanism... You know TCP use some specific algorithms so that the size of each TCP data packet is not the same... I'm not sure...